# Oracle pl/sql - Use associative array with user created record

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use an associative array with the element type of a user defined record. This array is to print the first name, last name, and grade of a student.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
TYPE studentRec IS RECORD (
  STUDENT_ID studentdb.student.student_id%TYPE,
  FIRST_NAME STUDENTDB.STUDENT.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
  LAST_NAME STUDENTDB.STUDENT.LAST_NAME%TYPE,
  GRADE STUDENTDB.GRADE.NUMERIC_GRADE%TYPE
);

CURSOR studentCursor IS
  SELECT STUDENT.STUDENT_ID, STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME, AVG(GRADE.NUMERIC_GRADE) AS GRADE
  FROM STUDENTDB.STUDENT
  INNER JOIN STUDENTDB.GRADE
  ON STUDENTDB.STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = STUDENTDB.GRADE.STUDENT_ID
  GROUP BY STUDENT.STUDENT_ID, STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME ;

sr studentRec;

TYPE studentArray IS TABLE OF studentRec INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

vars studentArray;

BEGIN


FOR rec IN studentCursor LOOP

  vars(rec.STUDENT_ID) := rec.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || rec.LAST_NAME || ' has grade ' || rec.GRADE;

END LOOP;

FOR ind IN vars.FIRST .. vars.LAST LOOP

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vars(ind));

END LOOP;



END;
```

This throws:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 27, column 27: PLS-00382: expression is
>   of wrong type ORA-06550: line 27, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 33, column 1: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE' ORA-06550: line 33, column 1: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `RECORD` declaration here, although you could use it if you know it. It is better to use `CURSOR%ROWTYPE.`  syntax as shown. There is also no need of associative array, as your indexes are going to be numbers anyway.

Also, instead of looping through the `CURSOR`, you could use `BULK COLLECT INTO`.

You cannot directly pass `vars(ind)` to `.PUT_LINE()`  . It should refer to specific column names.

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    CURSOR studentcursor IS
      SELECT student.student_id,
             student.first_name,
             student.last_name,
             AVG(grade.numeric_grade) AS GRADE
      FROM   studentdb.student
             inner join studentdb.grade
                     ON studentdb.student.student_id =
                        studentdb.grade.student_id
      GROUP  BY student.student_id,
                student.first_name,
                student.last_name;
    TYPE studentarray
      IS TABLE OF studentcursor%ROWTYPE;
    vars STUDENTARRAY;
BEGIN
    OPEN studentcursor;

    FETCH studentcursor BULK COLLECT INTO vars;

    FOR ind IN vars.first .. vars.last LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(vars(ind).student_id
                             ||','
                             || vars(ind).first_name
                             ||','
                             ||vars(ind).last_name
                             ||','
                             || vars(ind).grade);
    END LOOP;
END;
```